# Slow scrolling in Opera (11) using fixed position and text shadow

Tags: javascript, opera, css-position, css

I am using text-shadow for all **p** and **headline** tags (2px white glow for better readability), everything works fine until page is scrolled and javascript changes absolute positioning on one element to fixed - which I want to stay visible.

Is there any way apart of changing style for opera to make it scrolled smoothly? overflow:auto is not working in this case...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

it's hard to say 100% without seeing the code, but I guess that the way you've styled this page makes Opera do a lot of reflowing and painting when it is scrolled, and the combination of styles will make this a very expensive operation. (It would be nice to see a jsfiddle or get a link to the actual page, this would also make it simpler to advice on possible workarounds).

There are various fixes you could try - like keeping the element you want on-screen styled with position:absolute and move it from JavaScript after scroll events, or simply avoid setting position:fixed in Opera and letting the element scroll away for better scroll performance.

However, I'd strongly recommend that you first report a bug to Opera. Why?

**The reason and the genesis of the web is collaboration**. It may not be obvious to (understandably) frustrated web developers struggling with browser bugs, but they have a responsibility for helping browser vendors improve when they find problems, thereby contributing to moving the web forward. A minority browser like Opera admittedly has less development and QA staff resources, but to some extent support from the user community and "normal" web developers makes up for this and makes it possible also for smaller players to develop in the Web ecosystem. I think that's one of the web's strengths and the real reason why no single corporation has been able to dominate it.

So please report your issues and problems :)

Answer (score -3):

This is a problem with Opera, not any way you've written the code. Opera is a gigantic steaming pile of doo-doo with almost no market share, and you should use another browser.

That's basically all anyone could tell you here, unfortunately. I understand that everyone loves their browser of choice but some just don't handle these things well. Other examples: browser with a poor javascript engine rendering animations erratically and jerky, etc.